# Function one-to-one and onto from set to an other

Tags: math, set, discrete-mathematics, one-to-one

I saw somewhere that if we have a **one-to-one** function from sets X to Y mean that we have a **onto** function from Y to X. I can't understand it !! Someone can explain ??

Comment: That's only definition of onto and one-to-one

Comment: IMO the question should be migrated to math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function F: X → Y is **into** (aka **injective**) if every element of X is mapped to a distinct element of Y:

> ∀ x ∈ X, ∃ y ∈ Y | f(x) = y; x<sub>1</sub> ≠ x<sub>2</sub> ⇒ f(x<sub>1</sub>) ≠ f(x<sub>2</sub>)

It is **onto** (aka **surjective**) if every element of Y has some element of X that maps to it:

> ∀ y ∈ Y, ∃ x ∈ X | y = f(x)

And for F to be **one-to-one** (aka **bijective**), *both* of these things must be true.  Therefore, by definition a one-to-one function is both into and onto.

But you say "an **onto** function *from Y to X* must exist."  The "from Y to X" part might be what's tripping you up?  F is onto, but it's *from X to Y*.  The onto function from Y to X is F's inverse.  Which must also be bijective, and therefore onto.

Some authors use "one-to-one" as a synonym for "injective" rather than "bijective".  This disagreement is confusing, but we're stuck with it.  However, under *either* definition, the inverse of F exists (every injective function has an inverse) and is surjective (F is defined for every element of X, therefore the inverse of F maps some element of Y to every element of X).

Comment: I guess the "element of" symbol is &isin;

Comment: `&isin;` and `&in;` both work for me (and produce the same symbol), what browser are you using?

Comment: I see &in; rather than the symbol. I'm using Firefox 3.6.10.

Comment: Must be a FF4 new feature then.  Will change.

Comment: @Zack `&isin;` is new in HTML5.

Comment: One-to-one does not mean bijective; it's actually a synonym for injective. So in this case, F may not have an inverse.

Comment: @Jesse: I learned it as a synonym for bijective (and Wikipedia informs me that authors differ).  But all injective functions have inverses, and those inverses are surjective; see edit.

Comment: @jleedev: I fix it to be the actual Unicode characters.  Hopefully that works better cross-browser.

Comment: @Zack, every injective function has a *one-sided* inverse. An inverse, as usually defined, is such that fg = identity = gf, and a function has an inverse iff it is a bijection. (Also, I'm suspicious of wikipedia's statement that one-to-one function means bijective to some authors. I've never heard a mathematician use it that way (and wikipedia has no source). On the other hand, one-to-one correspondence is definitely a bijection.)

Comment: Well, I don't claim to be a mathematician, but I have never before heard this strict definition of inverse - in fact, I thought even injectivity was too strong a condition.  The definition I'm familiar with is, if `g(f(x)) == x` for all X *in the **image** of f* then g is the inverse of f.

Comment: Er, "for all y = f(x) in the image of f", I meant.

Comment: @Zack, read the wikipedia entry on inverses: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function. It reads pretty well (and notice that they use one-to-one as a synonym for injective).

Answer (score 3):

We can visualize this by drawing two circles, representing X and Y.  The dots in the circle represent the elements in each set.

The arrows represent your function or "mapping".

[image]

So **1-1** means that every dot in the X circle maps to a unique dot in the Y circle.

**Onto** means that every dot has an arrow going to it.  If you look at the picture, X is clearly not onto Y.   There are two dots with no arrows coming in.

Now look at the "reverse" mapping by flipping the arrows on the lines.

[image]

Notice how in the reverse transform, every element of X has at least one element from Y going to it?  That's the answer to your question.  The 1-1 in the first picture (*X to Y*) means the second picture (*Y to X*) must be onto.

The wikipedia article on [Surjective Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) explains this further.

Comment: Thanks for nice diagrams! in the second picture (the reverse) it's not a function from Y to X cause you have a free dot in Y set with no arrow going from it

Comment: You are correct.  The second diagram is not showing a function from the set of Y to the set of X.